# Entity Framework error : Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using Entity Framework to build my database. My model contain two entities:  `Entite` and `ApplicationUser` (see code below).

There are two relations between these entities:

1. One-to-Many: an `Entite` could contain one or many users. And a user belongs to one `Entite`.
2. One-to-One: an `Entite` must have one user as a responsible and a user can be responsible for only one `Entite`.

**Entite**:

```
public class Entite : AuditableEntity<int>
{
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public String code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public String Libelle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public String type { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("ResponsableId")]
        public int? ResponsableId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser responsable { get; set; }
        public int? RattachementEntiteId { get; set; }
        [Key, ForeignKey("RattachementEntiteId")]
        public virtual Entite rattachement { get; set; }

        public List<Entite> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Matricule { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateRecrutement { get; set; }      
        public int? entiteId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("entiteId")]
        public virtual  Entite entite { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to build the database using the `Add-Migration` command, I got this error :

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Any idea about this issue?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a small typo/error in your Entite model class.

The `ForeignKey` should be referencing your ApplicationUser, currently it is referencing itself, and a new Key will be generated for the `responsable`.

If we swap the `ForeignKey` reference to below, then this looks like it should solve your issue:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("responsable")]
public int? ResponsableId { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser responsable { get; set; }
```

Or you can swap the reference like you have done on your `rattachement`.

```
public int? ResponsableId { get; set; }
[Key, ForeignKey("ResponsableId ")]
public virtual ApplicationUser responsable { get; set; }
```